# как распарсить json файл

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

есть файл **products.json**

```
[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "stul"
 }
 {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "stol"
 }
]
```

и вот такая верстка

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
      <div class="product-container">
          <div class="product">
              <div class="id"></div>
              <div class="name"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

в `product-container` должны вставляться `product`
но их может быть много как сделать что бы все продукты распарсились в html c помощью **jquery** или это в принципе плохая идея, если их будет 1000 штук?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> или это в принципе плохая идея, если их будет 1000 штук?

Возможно вам нужно подгружать не все сразу, можно разделить на страницы или подгружать части на определенные действия юзера (`Lazy Loading`).

> как сделать что бы все продукты распарсились в html c помощью jquery

Если получаете JSON, не надо парсить.

```js
var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
//----------------------------------------------------------------
// Посылает AJAX GET запрос
$.ajax({
    url: url,
  })
  .done(function(data) { // Возвращает JSON 
    var res = '';
    $.each(data, function(i, v) {
      // Add DIV with text name and data-id with id
      $('<div/>', {
          class: 'id',
          text: v.name,
          "data-id": v.id
        })
        .appendTo('.product'); // Добавляет в DIV
    })

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="product-container">
  <div class="product">
    <!-------- Adding resutl here -------->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так:

```js
var data = [{
  "id": "0",
  "name": "stul"
}, {
  "id": "1",
  "name": "stol"
}, {
  "id": "4",
  "name": "json"
}]
$.each(data, function(i, u) {
  $('#product-container').append('<div class="product"><div class="id">' + u.id + '</div><div class="name">' + u.name + '</div></div>')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="product-container">
</div>
```

Для парсинга `JSON`:

```
$.getJSON("products.json", function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```